# logging: Is it acceptable to use try finally blocks for logging method start and end?

Tags: c#, java, logging

Consider a situation where a method with a lot of return statements needs to be logged, 
rather than doing,

```
    if(condition1)
    {
      calculation here
      do log
      return a
    }
    else if(condition2)
    {
      calculation here
      do log
      return b
    }
    else 
    {
      calculation here
      do log
      return c
    }
```

if the log statements are the same, is it better to log it this way?

```
try
{
    if(condition1)
    {
      calculation here
      return a
    }
    else if(condition2)
    {
      calculation here
      return b
    }
    else 
    {
      calculation here
      return c
    }                
}
finally
{
    do log
}
```

Are there any implications if we create a try finally block just for logging? What is the best practice?

Comment: Well, on the face of it, _if_ any of your `calculation here` blocks (or elsewhere) throw an exception, you will `do log` whereas in your old code it would throw without logging.

Comment: This approach is totally OK in my book. Cheers.

Comment: @Chris: indeed, you're right, not that this side effect is a bad thig, by the way.

Comment: I would question WHY your log statements are the same... they don't sound like very helpful log statements. How would you know which condition was hit?
If I've misunderstood, and they really should be the same, then maybe a boolean is better. And then a single if block at the end to log if successful.

Comment: @Vinzz Depends on what's being logged I suppose. If it's logging, "Calculation completed in X seconds!" when an exception is thrown, it might be fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just return at the end like this

```
var returnValue
if(condition1)
{
  calculation here
  returnValue = a
}
else if(condition2)
{
  calculation here
  returnValue = b
}
else 
{
  calculation here
  returnValue = c
}         
do log
return returnValue
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the (admitedly subjective) question?  The OP is not asking for a code review, he's asking about `try/finally` for log statements.

Answer (score 0):

To be a purist I would say it is always a bad practice to mix business logic with error handling.  Further, since this is the view from the ivory tower, it is also a bad practice to mix cross cutting concerns (logging) with business logic.

I would aim for this ...

```
if(condition1)
    {
      calculation here
       result = a
    }
    else if(condition2)
    {
      calculation here
      result = b
    }
    else 
    {
      calculation here
      result = c
    }      
    log stuff
    return result
```

Comment: `try/finally` is not "error handling".  (now `try/catch` on the other hand...)

Answer (score -1):

Its considered to be bad style to have multiple return statements --> complicated to see the  program flow. (not really an issue in such a small method, but it decreases the readability)

So consider to set a returnValue in the calculation blocks which will get returned at the end.

This allows you to have the logging at one point just before the return.